# Query related Facebook Integration into your website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I just need to know one thing that is suppose, a user comes to my website and find option to get login using Facebook account then once he login, can i get and save the details of user to my database for communication purposes?
If it's possible then what's the way to implement this feature in php? 
..

Good ideas will be welcomed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement a "Facebook login" to your website (as you can do it with Twitter, Google+, Steam and much more..).
To do it, you must use the OAuth2 API. You can do it with JavaScript or PHP.
Check [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login), it can help you.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is the way to let the user login using Facebook from your website, but i am asking for the next step?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile) in the doc, you can see how to get the user's informations: